# ЧПУ фильтр laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url, чпу, фильтр

Объясните принцип создания ЧПУ ссылок для фильтра на laravel, как это реализовать?

Есть строка URL = `site.ru/category/?param=1&param=2&param=3` и т.д
Необходимо, чтобы адресная строка выглядела `site.ru/category/param1/param2/param3`

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете в роуте указывать параметры в фигурных скобках, они будут переданы в контроллер.

```
Route::get('posts/{post}/comments/{comment}', function ($postId, $commentId) {
   //
});
```

В документации вам поможет этот раздел https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-parameters

Answer (score 0):

В путях:

```
Route::get('category/{firstParam}/{secondParam}/{thirdParam}', "TestController@get");
```

В контроллере метод

```
public function get(<FirstModel> $firstParam, <SecondModel> $secondParam, <ThirdModel> $thirdParam)
{
   // code...
}
```

`<FirstModel>` - тут класс модели, которая связанная с той или иной таблицей

тогда будет ссылка типа: http://site/category/1/2/3

Если нужно вместо цифр - свою строчку то согласно [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding):

в модель добавляем метод

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'url';
    }
```

Ну и конечно добавляем такую колонку в таблице модели. `url` - любое название может быть.

Теперь сылка будет http://site/category/your_url_1/your_url_2/your_url_3

Но теперь всегда нужно будет вытаскивать не по `id` а по `url` значение с базы)

Comment: `Route::any()` более универсальное решение, так как можно создавать динамические маршруты. Потому что внезапно может быть 4 параметра или 2.

Comment: @TotalPusher `any()` говорит о том, что может быть любой тип запроса(post, get, head,put, etc...) Если речь идет о параметрах то, там где может параметр не передаваться, нужно ставить знак вопроса, например `{param?}`